# OOP remove class instance

Tags: php, oop

I am rather new to using PHP OOP and attempting the following:

```
$this->array = new array();  
$this->array[1] = new myClass($UniqueName);
```

Within myClass I have a loop sending a message to the console every 5 seconds displaying the unique name. While the application is running new instances of the myClass will be created ( 1, 2, 3, 4, etc..), older ones become irrelevant and should be removed.

When I unset an array object the loop from that class keeps sending messages to the console.

```
unset($this->array[1])
```

My concern is that the class is not really gone wasting resources. As for the loop I could manually cancel it before running unset but it seems like its hiding my problem from view.

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help me understand if this is possible.

Comment: can you post the relevant code of `myClass`?

Comment: try set to null `$this->array[1] = null`

Comment: If you remove all references to the object the garbage collector automatically cleans it up for you. That said it's really hard to tell what you are doing without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my own problem. Here is a stripped down version I am testing with. The Issue is with the timer within myClass. It seems that because the timer is still running the class will not destruct. This has just been wishful thinking on my part that it would also terminate. Removing the timer allows the destruct to occur.

```
class myClass extends DefaultConfig {

  public $fileName;
  public $logLevel;
  public $loop;
  public $config;
  public $db;


  function __construct ($loop, $db, $config) {
    $this->fileName = 'myClassObject';
    $this->logLevel = 3;
    $this->loop = $loop;
    $this->config = new Config($config);
    $this->HB();
  }


  function __destruct() {
       print "Destroying " . $this->fileName . "\n";
  }
  public function HB(){
    $this->loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function($timer){
        $this->Logging(3, $this->fileName, $this->logLevel, "Server Message");
    });
  }
}
```